# Cannot debug a project with nested dependencies in Git submodules

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, asp.net-core, git-submodules

I have a solution with a sample .NET Core microservice that has dependencies on two projects (one of which is dependent on another and **dependencies** are set up using Git **submodules**). It builds fine, but when I try to **debug** the microservice, I get the **error**:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException'
> occurred in Unknown Module. Could not load file or assembly
> 'CommonLibrary, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.

I checked the `bin\Debug\net6.0` folder and the `CommonLibrary.dll` **file is there** along with all other dependencies.

I made a **copy** of the solution, included both dependency projects **without** using Git **submodules**, and it **worked fine**. I compared the `Debug\net6.0` folders in both solutions and they contain the same files (only the timestamps of the assemblies from the three projects are different). Any idea what could be going on here?

Here are some details (with project names redacted for clarity). The three .NET 6 projects include:

- `CommonLibrary` (has no dependencies on other projects)
- `CommonControllerLibrary` (depends on `CommonLibrary`)
- `SampleMicroservice` (depends on both `CommonLibrary` and `CommonControllerLibrary`)

I created 3 repos in GitLab and linked project dependencies via the Git submodules. On the file system, the directory structure for the `SampleMicroservice` project looks like this:

```
…
└── sample-microservice
    │
    ├── common-library
    │   └── CommonLibrary
    │       ├── CommonLibrary.csproj
    │       …
    ├── common-controller-library
    │   ├── common-library
    │   │   └── CommonLibrary
    │   │       ├── CommonLibrary.csproj
    │   │       …
    │   └── CommonControllerLibrary
    │       ├── CommonControllerLibrary.csproj
    │       …
    ├── SampleMicroservice.sln
    │
    ├── SampleMicroservice
    │       ├── SampleMicroservice.csproj
    │       ├── Bin
    │       │   └── Debug
    │       │       └── net6.0
    …       …
```

The `CommonLibrary` project is referenced twice in the solution, so in the Solution Explorer, it looks like this (I use solution folders to isolate the dependencies in the submodules from the main project):

```
Solution 'SampleMicroservice' (4 of 4 projects)
│
├── Submodules (folder)
│   ├── CommonLibrary (folder)
│   │   └── CommonLibrary (project)
│   │
│   └── CommonControllerLibrary (folder)
│       ├── CommonLibrary (project)
│       └── CommonControllerLibrary (project)
│
└── SampleMicroservice (project)
```

The `SampleMicroservice` project is dependent on the `CommonLibrary` project in the `CommonLibrary` solution folder and the `CommonControllerLibrary` in the `CommonControllerLibrary` solution folder.

I'm not sure if I messed up the projects when I set up the submodules, but I can't think of any other way to configure it. The main goal is to reuse projects across GitLab repos considering that some of the shared projects have nested dependencies (shared project `B` depends on shared project `A`, and project `C` depends on both `A` and `B`). TIA